# powershell debugging: script vs local, global and auto

Tags: powershell

When debugging Powershell, what is the difference between local vs script in VSCode?

I have looked for the current folder, calling a module(psm1) and it confused me that `$PSScriptRoot` did not give the right path.

I have a `main.ps1` importing some `module.psm1`.

In root folder(**myroot**), main.ps1:

```
-- Import-Module sub/module.psm1`
```

module.psm1:

```
...
Get-Folder() {return $PSScriptRoot}
..
```

This gives me the folder **myroot/sub** the modules folder , but if I do:
module.psm1:

```
...
Get-Folder() {return $local:MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot}
...
```

Then I get the right folder **myroot** calling the modul - so basically:

```
$local:MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot
```

vs

```
$script:MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot
```

vs

```
$PSScriptRoot
```

Comment: Can you highlight what you expect to get, and what you get instead in all cases?

Comment: Thanks, just added **myroot** for main and **myroot/sub'** for module folder - hope it helps.

Comment: You did not put what you expecting, so I am not sure what is your confusion about results. `return $PSScriptRoot`: you access `$PSScriptRoot` from `module.psm1` thus you get `module.psm1` location, which is `myroot/sub`. `return $local:MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot`: `$MyInvocation` automatic variable contains information about current command (which in current case is `Get-Folder` function) invocation. As you call it from `main.ps1` script, then `$MyInvocation.ScriptName`, `$MyInvocation.PositionMessage` and `$MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot` will contain information about `main.ps1` script.

Comment: @PetSerAl, add your comment as an answer. I interpret the OP "question" as "Whats the difference between the three different `PSScriptRoot` invocation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [about_automatic_variables documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#myinvocation):*

> Unlike the $PSScriptRoot and $PSCommandPath automatic variables, the
>   PSScriptRoot and PSCommandPath properties of the $MyInvocation
>   automatic variable contain information about **the invoker or calling
>   script, not the current script.**

From the [about_scopes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6#powershell-scopes):*

> Local: The **current** scope. The local scope can be the global scope or
>   any other scope.
>
> Script: The scope that is **created while a script file runs**. Only the
>   commands in the script run in the script scope. To the commands in a
>   script, the script scope is the local scope.

---

Combining these gives you the behavior you're seeing.

So basically if you want to find out the location of the currently running code, use `$PSScriptRoot`.

If you want to find out what's calling that code, use `$MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot`.

The `$local:` scope modifier will give you this from the currently running code, the `$script:` modifier will list the location of last calling script (i.e. these will be different if you called a function in another module from `module.psm1` because `$local:` will refer to `module.psm1` location and `$script:` will refer to `main.ps1` location, as `main.ps1` is the calling **script**).

If it still doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll put together some demo scripts.

<sub>*emphasis added</sub>